# Xcode no codesign_wrapper

Tags: xcode, code-signing, osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.4

Im using Xcode 4.4 on Mountain Lion OS X 10.8, to archive an iOS app however I keep receiving this error:

> (null):  There is no codesign_wrapper executable. Please reinstall the Xcode developer tools. (-19058)

Has anyone come across this problem or know how to solve it?

Thanks, Sami.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to install the command line tools via xcode?
they are located in the **Preferences** window's **Downloads** section and the **Components** tab.

[image: Xcode Downloaded Components]

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes across this as well...I was having trouble with this for hours while trying to submit the application with the Application Loader. Perhaps its a slightly different issue, since your getting this error while trying Archive, but for what its worthere this is/was my situation

. Using the "latest" Xcode 5.0.1 (past what I saw other threads saying - using 4.0.x), eventually installing Xcode 5.1 when released with the same error/issue. After upgrading, I believe I was still receiving the issue because I was still using the same (2.9) Application Loader from the first (5.0.1) Xcode. When I explicitly opened the new (2.9.1) Application Loader from (5.1) Xcode via Xcode --> Open Developer Tool --> Application Loader, the submittion process went futher. However failed for me for a different issue.

So it goes.